# How to configure dovecot as gmail imap proxy

Tags: proxy, imap, dovecot

I want to configure dovecot as gmail imap proxy. If any system in my network
wants to connect to imap.gmail.com,993 it has to go through the dovecot proxy.

Is it possible to setup such environment with dovecot? If yes, can you please
help me to configure my dovecot server.

Warm Regards

Supratik

Answer (score 3):

imapproxy does not support secure IMAP, port 993; which is required by Gmail. You need Perdition for that, here is a clue:
http://www.dataparadis.net/osp/gnu-linux-server/proxy-server/gmail-imap-proxy-imapproxy-perdition/

Answer (score 2):

Dovecot can act as an IMAP Proxy.
This might help
http://wiki.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase/ExtraFields/Proxy

Comment: I tried this configuration but not able configure the proxy server. Can you please tell me the exact steps to configure the proxy server.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called [imapproxy](http://www.imapproxy.org) and it may suit your purposes better.

Comment: I installed imapproxy in a RHEL 5.3 system, but not able to configure it properly. Can you please help me to configure my proxy server. I am also not able to find any good documentation on it.

Comment: I checked with all possibilities and finally came to know that imapproxy do not support imaps (993) which is used by imap.gmail.com.
Can you please suggest any other imap proxy which will support imaps (993)

Comment: OP is asking about dovecot.